# DateValue is leaving some dates as strings

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

Using Office 365 - but some users access files via older versions. Standard and system date format is DD/MM/YYYY. Original data also formatted to look this way.

I have a range of cells that appear as dates, but some are formatted as text.
The data comes from a system extract so I can't help the way it is formatted originally.

I use this data to create automated reports using VBA, but for some reason DATEVALUE seems to leave some of the dates as strings.

I have tried coding it several different ways but cannot get this small piece of it to work and I keep getting cells still as text.

If I apply a formula manually in the sheet, it works. I have checked by applying breaks, and that line of code is running (i.e. the IF statement criteria is being met where is should be).

Since the code moves data from one sheet to another, I know all the variables are correct and everything else works perfectly except this.

See below for more info:

**Code**:

```
        If Replace(Field32, "/", "") <> Field32 Then
            Field32 = DateValue(Field32)
        End If

        If Replace(Field34, "/", "") <> Field34 Then
            Field34 = DateValue(Field34)
        End If
```

I have tried CDate. I have also tried formatting field first using Format(Field32, "dd/mm/yyyy"), I have tried a couple of different ways of checking if the field is already a date. I tried converting all to text and then applying DATEVALUE to every row, it didn't work, just got all text. I have also tried just applying DATEVALUE to every row, but it seems like DATEVALUE is not working at all as it didn't return errors where there are already dates.. What am I doing wrong?

**Data After Code has executed**:

As you can see, the dates stored as text are still stored as text and as a result some other calculation fields don't work

[image]

With fields formatted as number to make it clear to see which ones are now dates:

[image]

Comment: "*The data comes from a system extract so I can't help the way it is formatted originally.*" What does this mean?  What kind of data is this?  How does it get into Excel?

Comment: What is your default date format?  Is it mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy ?   All of the non-converted dates have the first part >12 so it seems Excel can't make a date from them as it expects the first part to be the month (and so your other dates may be wrongly-converted)   You need to find out the exact format of the dates in the exported data, then convert them based on that format (ie. split on "/" and re-combine the parts to make a correct/valid date)

Comment: `arr = Split(inputValuehere, "/"): actualDate = DateSerial(arr(2),arr(1),arr(0))`

Comment: Default date is dd/mm/yyyy - to clarify - none of the dates converted. the dates shown on right are where the original format was already a date. The ones on the left, starting with 20/01/2022 are the ones stored as text and not converting

Comment: Data is extracted into excel sheet from another system. It comes out as .xls with no errors and data all in named columns but its not great in terms of consistent formatting. This workbook picks up that auto extract to use for reporting

Comment: If the exported dates are all formatted as text in dd/mm/yyyy format  and your default date format is the same, then I don't know why only some of them converted, since they should all be valid under your system settings.

Comment: @TimWilliams How do I go about applying the function you added above? What do I define arr as? Variant?

Comment: Maybe you can post a little more of your existing code - how are you identifying the ranges you need to work on for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```vb
    Dim c As Range, arr
    
    For Each c In Range("B25:B33").Cells
        'if formatted as text and content looks like a date
        If c.NumberFormat = "@" And c.Text Like "##/##/####" Then
            arr = Split(c.Text, "/")
            c.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"   'set format *before* value
            c.Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
        End If
    Next c
```